# Apply a function to elements of matrix on condition

Tags: r, function, apply

I'm looking to change the value of a certain entry in a matrix based on the value of another entry. Its easiest to explain with an example:
Matrix

```
ABC-DEF 1 0 0 0  
HIJ-KLM 0 0 0 0  
NOP-QRS 1 0 0 0  
KLM-HIJ 0 0 0 0  
DEF-ABC 0 0 0 0  
QRS-NOP 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, each of the rows in the matrix above has a counterpart (e.g. ABC-DEF's counterpart is DEF-ABC).

Is there some way in which  I can look to see which rows have a one in the first column and then place a 2 in the fourth column of its counterpart? In the above example then:

```
ABC-DEF 1 0 0 0  
HIJ-KLM 0 0 0 0  
NOP-QRS 1 0 0 0  
KLM-HIJ 0 0 0 0  
DEF-ABC 0 0 0 2  
QRS-NOP 0 0 0 2
```

I'm quite stuck and would really appreciate any help! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your column names are `V1`,...,`V5`, you can do something like this :

```
values <- d$V1[d$V2==1]
d$V5[d$V1 %in% gsub("(...)-(...)","\\2-\\1", values)] <- 2
```

Which will give :

```
       V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 ABC-DEF  1  0  0  0
2 HIJ-KLM  0  0  0  0
3 NOP-QRS  1  0  0  0
4 KLM-HIJ  0  0  0  0
5 DEF-ABC  0  0  0  2
6 QRS-NOP  0  0  0  2
```

If, instead of a data frame, your data is a numeric matrix `m` with row names, you can do :

```
values <- rownames(m)[m[,1]==1]
m[rownames(m) %in% gsub("(...)-(...)","\\2-\\1", values),4] <- 2
```

**EDIT :** To understand what the code is doing, you must see that :

```
gsub("(...)-(...)","\\2-\\1", values)
```

will replace any character string in the `values` vector of the form `XXX-YYY` by `YYY-XXX` via regexp matching. The result is a character vector of the "counterparts" of `values`. Then we use `%in%` to select every rows whose rownames appear in these counterpart values, and assign `2` in the fourth column for these rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just input that code, but I can't seem to get it to work. In my matrix I don't actually have the "-", that was just to make it easier to read, so I tried this: `m[rownames(m) %in% gsub("......","\\2-\\1", values),4] = 2` instead, both with a bracket around the "..." and without, but neither seems to work. Thanks again

Comment: @Mike maybe try `gsub("(...)(...)","\\2\\1", values)` ?

Comment: Amazing! that worked. Would you mind explaining to me what the code is doing? I understand the first line, its just finding the rows which match a condition. But the second line I don't understand at all. Thanks! –

Comment: @Mike Just added an explanation to my answer. Hope it is clear enough.